# Struts 2 action linked to a clickable link

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to add an action to a link inside a list item

It's inside a form:

```
<form name="searchForm" method="post" action="searchThis" id="querySubmiter">
```

Inside a list:

```
<li><a href="somePage.jsp"><img src="img/Logo/myLogo.png"/></a>
```

I'm a bit clueless as to how to make the connection. 
Is it possible?

Comment: You can't send a POST directly through an anchor link. You would need to add a javascript onclick event.

Comment: so add some javascript to it?

Comment: Do you want to post the form or just execute an action? In the first case try and use either javascript or `<s:submit>` in the second try `<s:a action="...">`. Btw, why don't you use `<s:form>` here?

Comment: because I forgot it existed. and this started out as a pure html project, I didn't do it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Struts 2 tags like

```
<s:a action="searchThis"><img src="<s:url value="/img/Logo/myLogo.png"/>"/></s:a>
```

---

There would be generated an anchor tag with the image. Note to use `<s:url>` tag to correctly define the path to the static resource. Also combined with `<s:param>` tag you could construct any link. See the documentation with example of the [`<s:a>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/a-tag.html).

Comment: hey, this works, thanks! I don't need a stupid form or anything!